# How do I stop text from showing up at the back of a revolving image?

Tags: css, animation

First off, here is the [link](https://codepen.io/blackyurizan/pen/KqrBev) to see what I am talking about. It is going to be a little bit hard to understand what I am saying without seeing it. I have two images in one container if you hover over the container the front image rotates out and the back image rotates in. The rotation is fine but the text from the front image is being shown at the back of the image. I think the reason is simply that I have translateX on both texts. But only the front image text is shown in the back and not the other way around. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Code

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 3em 0;
}

.img-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(60px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.inverse .text {
  transform: translateZ(60px);
}

.text h3 {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-self: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.text p {
  max-width: 66%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.inverse {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(60, 60, 221, 0.5), rgba(9, 9, 170, 0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
}


/* .visit{
      display:inline-block;
      text-align:center;
      background:white;
      color:blue;
      text-transform:capitalize;
      max-width:100px;
      padding:1em 2em;
      text-align:center;
      margin:0;
      border-style:none;
      border-radius: 25px;
    } */

.img.normal {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

.img-container:hover .normal {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(60, 60, 221, 0.5), rgba(9, 9, 170, 0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
}

.img-container:hover .inverse {
  transform: rotateY(0deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="img-container">
    <div class="img-fluid img normal">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-fluid img inverse">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>this is a summary something something something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Should use a snippet....

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is following link.

**[Here is your working code](https://codepen.io/Lokeshg27/pen/NgeWRG?editors=1100#0)**

If you don't want to remove `translateZ` then just add `backface-visiblity: hidden;`

Like

```
.text{
  color:white;
   transform-style:preserve-3d;
   transform: translateZ(60px);
  text-align:center;
  font-size:36px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:arial;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
  backface-visibility:hidden; /* Added */
}
```

Working snippet of your answer without removing `translateZ`.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 3em 0;
}

.img-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(60px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Added */
}

.inverse .text {
  transform: translateZ(60px);
}

.text h3 {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-self: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.text p {
  max-width: 66%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.inverse {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(60, 60, 221, 0.5), rgba(9, 9, 170, 0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
}


/* .visit{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  background:white;
  color:blue;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  max-width:100px;
  padding:1em 2em;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  border-style:none;
  border-radius: 25px;
} */

.img.normal {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

.img-container:hover .normal {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(60, 60, 221, 0.5), rgba(9, 9, 170, 0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
}

.img-container:hover .inverse {
  transform: rotateY(0deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="img-container">
    <div class="img-fluid img normal">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-fluid img inverse">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>this is a summary something something something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The second example to get it easily, by following.

```css
.card-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 12px;
  perspective: 900px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FEC606;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 27px 55px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 17px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card-container:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">Hello</div>
    <div class="back">User</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. backface-visibility has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change class `.text` into the below and the text won't rotate with the image:

```
.text{
  color:white;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(60px), opacity:0;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:36px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:arial;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
}
```

```css
.container{
  margin:auto;
  width:1200px;
  border-right:1px solid grey;
  border-left:1px solid grey;
  padding:3em 0;
  
}

.img-container{
  display:block;
  max-width:800px;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  
}

.img-fluid{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
}

.img{
  height:400px;
  background-image:
   linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0,0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
  background-size: cover ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.text{
  color:white;
   transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(60px), opacity:0;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:36px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:arial;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
  
}
.inverse .text{
  transform:translateZ(60px);
}


.text h3{
  text-decoration:none;
  align-self:center;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  
}

.text p{
  max-width:66%;
  margin:10px auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.inverse{
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image:
   linear-gradient(rgba(60, 60, 221,0.5), rgba(9, 9, 170,0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
  
}

/* .visit{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  background:white;
  color:blue;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  max-width:100px;
  padding:1em 2em;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  border-style:none;
  border-radius: 25px;
} */

.img.normal{
  transform: rotateY(0);
  
}

.img-container:hover .normal{
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  background-image:
   linear-gradient(rgba(60, 60, 221,0.5), rgba(9, 9, 170,0.7)), url(http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg);
  
}



.img-container:hover .inverse{
  transform:rotateY(0deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="img-container">
    <div class="img-fluid img normal">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Header</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-fluid img inverse">
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>this is a summary something something something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer was one of the solutions I came up with. But, I wanted to see if it was possible to keep translateZ on both text classes, without them overlapping each other. Is there a possible way to do this

Comment: I have adjusted the code. Opacity: 0 was added and translateZ stayed in place.